# Alert box on mouse click using image mapping

Tags: javascript, html

How do I produce an information text or alert box on mouse click on image coordinates?

Following is the line of mapping code I tried:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="523,137,658,160" href="#" onclick='alert("Pt.#xxxxx - $xxx.xx")' title="Pt.#xxxxx">
```

Comment: You probably forgot to surround your area with < and >?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/157wq0zq/

```
click on planets or the sun ( sample from w3schools )<br>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets"
usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="javascript: alert('the sun')" alt="Sun" >
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="javascript: alert('the mercury')" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="javascript: alert('the venus')" alt="Venus">
</map>
```